# Isomorphism of a closure system and a topped complete lattice

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, lattice-orders

It is in general true that if a closure system $\mathcal{F}$ on a given ground set $\Omega$ is order isomorphic to a complete lattice $\mathcal{G}$ on $P(\Omega)$ having $P(\Omega)$ as its top element, then $\mathcal{G}$ could fail to be a closure system? As an example, I took $\Omega=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and consider the set systems $\mathcal{F}=\{\Omega,\{a,b,c\},\{b,c,d\},\{b,c\}\}$ and $\mathcal{G}=\{\Omega,\{a,b,c\},\{b,c,d\},\emptyset\}$: they are order isomorphic as complete lattices, but not as closure system. Is my argument correct?

Comment: $\mathcal{G}$ is not even a closure system?

Comment: No, it is not intersection closed

Comment: Then how could we even talk about $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ being "isomorphic as a closure system". For that they'd both have to be one first.

Comment: In fact, in my counterexample, I showed that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a closure system, whose underlying lattice is order isomorphic to the underlying lattice of a topped set system $\mathcal{G}$, does not imply that $\mathcal{G}$ is also a closure system. Here the situation is different from what happens for instance between posets and complete lattices, i.e. if a poset is order isomorphic to a complete lattice, then it is also a complete lattice.

Comment: A closure system on $P(\Omega)$ need not always be a lattice. Lattice and closure system are incomparable structure types, one could say.

Comment: You're affirmation is false: see Davey-Priestley pag. 148 "Any topped $\bigcap$-structure (i.e. any closure system) is a COMPLETE LATTICE in which meet is given by set intersection, but, regrettably, join is usually not given by union.

Comment: What about all subsets of $\Bbb Z$ of size at most $3$, say? That's a closure system but not a lattice?

Comment: No, because such a collection does not have the top element, namely $\mathbb{Z}$. You must add it in order to get a closure system. In particular, with such a choice, you will get also a complete lattice.

Comment: I didn't know about the top element requirement..

Comment: Ah ok, here is the problem. The definition of closure system forecasts the presence of the top element. This is because in my question assumed $\mathcal{G}$ to have the top element. Now, reading again my question, is my argument correct? Well, the real problem is the following: closure systems are not closed under order isomorphisms, so I need to consider a stricter collection of isomorphisms (those preserving intersections) in order to get an invariance-like result.

Comment: In my answer I do say that your example is correct, don't I?

Comment: I accepted your answer. Please, read the final part of my last comment. Can you spend few words on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, your example indeed shows that these systems (under inclusion as order) are both isomorphic to the simple lattice with top and bottom and two incomparable elements inbetween (it probably has a standard name; maybe "diamond"?) and one *is*  a closure system and the other is not. A lattice is more general, one could say. Preserving order is more "lenient" than preserving exact intersections, which is the appropriate way to define isomorphism/structure-preservingness for closure systems, one could say.

Comment: More generally, if you strip some meaning off from an algebraic structure, then originally different structures may turn out the same. It's like taking vertex-colored graphs and forgetting the coloring, or taking different permutation groups and looking at them as abstract groups, forgetting the permutations.

Comment: @JukkaKohonen Here the real issue is  that a closure system isomorphism must preserve intersections exactly and for lattice an order isomorphism is enough. Order is more "forgiving".